# On complete listener for ApiFuture<WriteResult> with Firestore Admin

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Is there a Firebase Admin equivalent of an OnComplete listener? My aim is to update a 'recently searched' list on a document, followed by a status update on whether the action was completed or not.

```
private static void addSearch(String search, String uid) {

        DocumentSnapshot currentUser = firestoreDB.collection("users").document(uid).get().get();

        ArrayList<String> retrievedSearches = (ArrayList<String>) currentUser.get("searches");
        retrievedSearches.add(search);

        ApiFuture<WriteResult> writer = firestoreDB.collection("users").document(uid).update("searches", retrievedSearches);

        //Oncomplete listener to check when the above^ write has been completed

}
```

**Updated (added callback)**

```
private static void addSearch(String search, String uid) {

        DocumentSnapshot currentUser = firestoreDB.collection("users").document(uid).get().get();

        ArrayList<String> retrievedSearches = (ArrayList<String>) currentUser.get("searches");
        retrievedSearches.add(search);

        ApiFuture<WriteResult> writer = firestoreDB.collection("users").document(uid).update("searches", retrievedSearches);

        //Oncomplete listener to check when the above^ write has been completed

        ApiFutures.addCallback(writer, new ApiFutureCallback<WriteResult>(){
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                // TODO handle failure
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(WriteResult result) {
                // TODO handle success
            }
        } );

    }
```

[.addCallBack is deprecated?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4FW4.png)

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation of the [ApiFutures](https://googleapis.github.io/api-common-java/0.2.0/apidocs/index.html?com/google/api/core/ApiFutures.html) class, the completion of an operation can be achieved when using callbacks.

More useful information regarding this topic, you can also find in this [post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/firebase-asynchronous-operations-with-admin-java-sdk-82ca9b4f6022).

Comment: Isn't that deprecated? Getting this from IDE - 'addCallback(com.google.api.core.ApiFuture<V>, com.google.api.core.ApiFutureCallback<? super V>)' is deprecated

Comment: In the [docs](https://googleapis.github.io/api-common-java/0.2.0/apidocs/com/google/api/core/ApiFutures.html#addCallback-com.google.api.core.ApiFuture-com.google.api.core.ApiFutureCallback-) it doesn't say that, right?

Comment: It doesn't no, am i implementing it wrong? Documentation is a bit vague. I've updated the code with the added callback. [Github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/3861)

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/3861) out?

Comment: I have (it's linked in the previous comment) but have not had any luck.